# How to search for word definitions?

Tags: android, api, search, dictionary

I am working on a app in android where I need to select a word and display its definition from Google. Do I have to use some search API provided by Google, or another API?

An example will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary) is no longer available, but even when it was, the API was [unavailable to 3rd parties](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html). Instead, I found several alternative options.

---

### XML Dictionary Exchange Format

You could use [XDXF](http://xdxf.revdanica.com/) to [download a flat-file dictionary](http://xdxf.revdanica.com/down/) in your desired language, and use a hash table to index the file appropriately.

This has two distinct advantages:

- Network access is not required to support dictionary look-ups
- It's ultimately more flexible because the data can be easily manipulated (sorted, filtered, specially formatted) to better support application design & requirements.

---

### Abbreviations.com API

If you prefer not to home-brew your own hash-table, *abbreviations.com* has a [public dictionary API](http://www.abbreviations.com/definitions_api.asp) that uses REST to obtain definition information in XML format for a given word.

Sample Request URL:

```
http://www.abbreviations.com/services/v1/defs.aspx?tokenid=tk324324&word=consistent
```

Sample Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result>
    <term>consistent, uniform</term>
    <definition>the same throughout in structure or composition</definition>
    <partofspeech>adj</partofspeech>
    <example>
       bituminous coal is often treated as a consistent and homogeneous product
    </example>
  </result>
</results>
```

Comment: Hey i didn't get much what you just said.Can u explain it with an example.