# F#: Link actual word/definitions dictionary to code

Tags: f#

I'm running into a search issue with my question.  I'm trying to link an actual dictionary (e.g., words with definitions) to some code I'm writing in `F#`.  Specifically, I'm using `FsVerbalExpressions` to identify whitespace-separated strings and would like to look each string up in an actual dictionary to determine if they're words or not.

The problem I'm having is that when I search on SO (or Google or anywhere else) for "link dictionary to F#" or "F# dictionary library" or some other permutation of "F#" and "dictionary," I get hits on how to use the `dictionary` collection in `F#`.

I'm hoping someone out there has some insight into how to link a dictionary, though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740995/how-to-search-for-word-definitions) has given me some directions to alternatives if I can't find exactly what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the dictionary that you want to "link"? Where do you get it from, in what format? Etc.

Comment: Honestly, I was hoping that there was a "definition" library available for `F#`.

Comment: "Definition" of what?

Comment: Realistically, the best method is just to use a library designed for C#

Comment: I don't think you can get a good answer here - there is no library that would give you definitions of word meanings (or whatever you are actually looking for) for F#. You'll most likely need to use some online service or perhaps dictionary you can download, but finding that is not a question for the StackOverflow format.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Agreed.  I was thinking that I'd be able to find some sort of F# implementation of "Webster's Dictionary" but, upon looking into it further, it seems like using some sort of online service that has a public dictionary API is the best way to go.

I voted to close this question as well.